# get 0 when emptyornull values else max(id) when column datatype is numeric in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I have one doubt in sql server

get 0 when emptyornull values  else max(id) when column datatype i is numeric  in sql server 
Table : empid

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empid](
    [id] [numeric](11, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empid] ([id]) VALUES (NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[empid] ([id]) VALUES (CAST(6 AS Numeric(11, 0)))
GO
```

based on above data I want output like below

```
id

6
```

I tried like below

```
select case when isnull( max(id),'')='' then cast (0  as numeric) else max(id end test from )
    [Test].[dbo].[empid]
```

but  above query is getting error 
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 9
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

suppose no records in table then maxid will get 0

please tell me  how to write a query to achive this task in sql server

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you actually using here as well? 2008 is now completely out of support.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the COALESCE function that gives you the ability to replace a potential NULL with whatever you wish (0 in your current case) as so:

```
select coalesce(id, 0) as id from [dbo].[empid];
```

Comment: suppose records have empty space then its will not work

Comment: @gbalu, In the current format, the column [id] cannot accept empty spaces as it is defined as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `''`?  Just use `0`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(id,0) AS test
FROM dbo.empid;
```

`ISNULL` returns the datatype of the first parameter, and with the SQL you had, you were therefore implicitly trying to convert `''` to a `numeric`, which was failing.

Comment: suppose records have empty space then its will not work

Comment: @gbalu `id` is defined `[numeric](11, 0)` it **can't** have an empty space. `' '` is not a numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to use COALESCE function provided by SQL

```
COALESCE(arg1, arg2[, argN])
```

what it does is it takes N arguments

- arg1 is a column that can be null
- arg2 is a column that can be null
- argN is the value that you want to replace it with

Query could be

```
 SELECT COALESCE(Id, 0) as Id FROM [dbo].[empid]
```